# How To Use Regex In String List?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to use regex to find a pattern across a string list:

```
static List<Integer> getMatchingIndexes(List<String> list, String regex) {
    ListIterator<String> li = list.listIterator();
    List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    System.out.println(list.matches("\\w.*"));
    while(li.hasNext()) {
        int i = li.nextIndex();
        String next = li.next();
        if(Pattern.matches(regex, next)) {
            indexes.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(indexes);
    return indexes; 
}
```

It looks like nothing is showing up int he list, when I try to see if there are any matches (list.matches("\w.*")); (just an example, not the actual regex), it keeps giving me an error:

The method matches(String) is undefined for the type List

How can I use regex on this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through the list (using a [for-each](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html) loop) and check for matches:

```
for (String s : list) {
    s.matches("\\w.*");
    // Do stuff here.
}
```

Comment: @johnc. `s` is the currently selected `String` from `list` as it iterates.

Answer (score 1):

Try to iterate through each item in the `List<Integer>` by the following:

```
for(Integer i : indexes){
    System.out.println(i.toString().matches("\\w.*"));
}
```

The above is equivalent to:

```
for(int i=0; i<indexes.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(indexes.get(i).toString().matches("\\w.*"));
}
```